# Python - Searching items in a text file

Tags: python, string, list, parsing

I am writing a script in Python that searches a text file for various items and once it finds the item it moves onto the next.  In this case I am finding a person then the items attributed to that person.  But what is happening is I keep getting the first person repeated the amount of times a person is found in the list.  I was able to do this successfully with other items outside of finding the person but it seems that when it comes to finding the person, it repeats.  Please see what I have so far.  I have stripped everything that works out just to concentrate on this one particular issue.

```
    text = open("Register.txt",'rt') #opens the Register text file
    Register = text.read()

    length = len(Register)
    lines = Register.splitlines() #Breaks the .txt file down into their own lines


    for line in lines: #searches each line for the following statement
        if line.find("Per End")!=-1:  #searches each line for the ("*") item and asks if it is True
            nameline = Register.index(line)
            namebegin = nameline-15
            print nameline
            print Register[namebegin:nameline]
```

There are about 60 people in the text and this code will only list the first one 60 times. Each one is followed by the "Per End" which is why I used it to find the people in the text.  From there it is supposed to locate the index and subtract by a few items to make sure the whole name outputs.

Comment: It's best to include a **minimal** example of your input with questions - it makes it easier for to see what you are doing and it gives us something to test our solutions with.

Comment: I agree with @wwii .  Also have you tried with list index eg :  `for i in range(len(lines))`